# Visual Studio Web development for Mac OS

Tags: visual-studio

I have macbook pro and I have recently released visual studio. But there is no Web development module in that.
Can anyone tell me, How to create website in visual studio for Mac?
or 
I need to switch to Windows.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are indeed new. Under most circumstances, you can do almost everything on your Mac (I am a heavy Mac and Windows user).

You should start by looking at the menu. (top right corner) after launching Visual Studio. Then, go to Visual Studio. > Extensions > Gallery

Pick what you want (for example, Web Development > Web Project Support) and install.

that's it. Like this, you can install whatever you want.

(but, just to confirm, no you don't need to switch to windows or buy a windows machine just for this)